# facebook og meta tag duplicated title

Tags: facebook, og-meta

I have a problem sharing in facebook. I think i have correctly og:meta title but facebook duplicate title.

This is the link:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pisos.afys.cat%2Fvivienda%2Fesgl%25C3%25A8sia%2Fplanta-baja_en_sant-joan-de-vilatorrada_4290167.3377.html%23f

Can anyone help me?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

After a re-scrape, debug tool shows the following message:

> Object at URL `http://www.pisos.afys.cat/vivienda/esgl%C3%A8sia/planta-baja_en_sant-joan-de-vilatorrada_4290167.3377.html#f` of type `website` is invalid because the given value `494641230470` for property `fb:admins` could not be parsed as type `fbid`.

`494641230470` is the id of a Facebook page, not of a user profile. Pages can not moderate comments.

Fix this error first, and after that re-scrape again, to update Facebook's cache of your page.

Comment: What can i do?

Thx

Comment: Go fix your broken HTML code as well (the FB scraper can be picky when it comes to invalid HTML) - you are outputting a script element even before the doctype and html element. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pisos.afys.cat%2Fvivienda%2Fesglèsia%2Fplanta-baja_en_sant-joan-de-vilatorrada_4290167.3377.html%23f

Comment: Before going perfectly and is taking the metas correctly, you can see them listed. It makes no sense to correct the HTML code when all you use are the metas and is collecting properly. Besides it is not in my hand correct html.

Any idea?

Thx